# How to stop Windows 10 working at night?

Tags: windows, windows-10

My Windows 10 laptop is near me while sleeping. It lives its own life. Last night I woke up to the laptop periodically spinning up the fans full power, which is very noisy.

How do I make windows sleep as of really sleep (don't do anything) at night in a schedule (ie. from 11:00pm until 7:00am don't do anything) without actually turning it off?

Comment: Not the answer you're looking for, but maybe even better: using power management, you can set how much the CPU can be utilized. By setting this to as low as 5% all tasks on the laptop will be so slow that the CPU doesn't warm up, and its not getting hot. You can then make a profile and use scheduled task to switch based on time or action between profiles. The laptop will still perform its tasks, but you may not be bothered by it anymore. It will also make sure the battery drain is really low, so you can actually work on your laptop for a lot longer.

Comment: Set it to hibernate and that will fix it for you.

Comment: Hibernate actually turns it off

Answer (score 3):

There is likely a Windows Update or system maintenance scheduled task that is waking your PC, this might also explain the full fan speed if it was doing something intensive.

There is an option to prevent your PC being awakened through scheduled tasks.

1. Open the Start Menu and search for "Power Plan", open "Edit Power Plan".
   [image: Power Plan Settings]
2. Click on "Change advanced power settings".
   [image: Advanced power settings button]
3. Expand Sleep > Allow wake timers > Setting. Set this to Disabled.
   [image: Power Options]

The "Edit power plan" option will open settings for whichever power plan you are currently using.
Consider changing this setting on all of your plans available by clicking this drop-down:

[image: Adding option for each plan.]

If this option isn't present in the Power Plan settings then you can try these commands instead:

1. First we need the GUID of your current power plan, open `cmd` and run `powercfg /l`.

```
PS C:\Users\TEst> powercfg /l

Existing Power Schemes (* Active)
-----------------------------------
Power Scheme GUID: 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e  (Balanced) *
Power Scheme GUID: 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c  (High performance)
Power Scheme GUID: a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a  (Power saver)
```

The entry with the * next to it is your active plan, copy the GUID for me it is `381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e`.

2. Now run `powercfg  /SETACVALUEINDEX <GUID> 238c9fa8-0aad-41ed-83f4-97be242c8f20 bd3b718a-0680-4d9d-8ab2-e1d2b4ac806d 0`

For example, for me I ran `powercfg  /SETACVALUEINDEX 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e 238c9fa8-0aad-41ed-83f4-97be242c8f20 bd3b718a-0680-4d9d-8ab2-e1d2b4ac806d 0`

If this runs with no output then it's worked, if it says something like `The power scheme, subgroup or setting specified does not exist.` then either the GUID entered for your plan doesn't exist, or this power option doesn't exist in your registry.

You can see the available power settings for `sleep` in the registry under `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\238c9fa8-0aad-41ed-83f4-97be242c8f20`

Comment: I only have sleep after, and hibernate after options under sleep

Comment: @GergőHorváth I've added some additional steps you can try since the options aren't there.